# AXIOS CORS PROBLEM. Server has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" but Axios can't see it. why?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, cors, axios

I have a CORS problem with axios.

The server is fine, I am sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * on all routes.

I can even login using the same backend, but for some reason logout is not working, axios can't see the headers.

I made a video:
https://youtu.be/vHfyk8BteLA

Can somebody explain that? When I check the network with a GET on the browser the header is there, but when the get is triggered by axios the header vanishes.

```
logout = () => {

        const token = window.localStorage.getItem('jwt_access_token');
        const request = axios.post('https://localhost/vintiapi/public/api/logout?token='+token);

        this.setSession(null);

        request.then(response => {

            console.log('logout');

        });
};
```

Comment: The error mentions that the preflight request doesn't get the header - if you're using the `cors` module, see: [Enabling CORS Pre-Flight](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight)

Comment: awesome! that was it! I added the headers in the normal request but not in preflight. got it work finally! thank you!!

Comment: Great! I'll add an answer so you can resolve your question.

Answer (score 2):

The error message suggests that it's the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) that's not getting the header. If you're using the `cors` module, you'll need to handle the [OPTIONS request yourself](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight):

```
// From: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.options('/products/:id', cors()) // enable pre-flight request for DELETE request
app.del('/products/:id', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Or you can enable it for all preflight requests:

```
app.options('*', cors())
```